# How can I read disk image file in hdfs using spark-shell or spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I want to read disk image file in hdfs using spark.
Now I use this command to parse mft of disk image file in spark.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl0Dr.png)

Disk file's address is hdfs://IP:9000/image-test/EMP01.001 and
the library of parse mft of disk image is in hdfs://IP:9000/image-test/ntfs_parser.
How can I access these files using spark-shell or spark-submit?

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04, Hadoop 3.2.1, Spark 3.0.1.

Comment: The pic's code is
"$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-sumbit --master yarn ./mftparse.py export -o 0 -i ./EMP01.001 -t csv -e ./output_01.csv".

Comment: Hi! Can you explain to us, what you have tried so far?